# How to add ImageView's that are depending on the text of the TextView in a ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, imageview, switch-statement

I have a custom `ListView` with a `RowItem` that contains `TextView` and a `ImageView` .
The `RowItems` will be added dynamically.

I just want to know how to add the `ImageView` to a specific text in the `TextView`.

So if in the `TextView` stands "Title1" ,the `ImageView` "R.drawable.ic_title1" should be added to the `RowItem` .

---

Here is my Code

```
class SessionItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Map> {

        final ArrayList<Map> values;
        Context context;

        SessionItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Map> values) {
            super(context, R.layout.session_list_layout_row, values);
            this.values = values;
            this.context = context;
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.session_list_layout_row, parent, false);

            TextView tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.stepTime);
            final int rowId = (Integer) values.get(position).get("id");
            int beepStringId = getResources().getIdentifier("exercise_typ_" + values.get(position).get("type"), "string", getPackageName());

            rowView.setTag(rowId);

            tv.setText(getResources().getString(beepStringId));
            ImageView image =(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


                switch(position){

                case 1 : image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_title1);
                    break;

                case 2 : image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_title2);
                    break;
            }

            ImageButton deleteSession = (ImageButton) rowView.findViewById(R.id.session_item_del);
            deleteSession.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    /*if (!startStopToggle.isChecked()) {*/
                    sessionAdapter.remove(values.get(position));
                    sessionAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                }
            });

            return rowView;
        }

        //in your adapter getAllPlayers() would be something like this
        public List<String> getAllPlayers() {
            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Map item : values) {
                int beepStringId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("exercise_typ_"
                        + item.get("type"), "string", context.getPackageName());
                String str = context.getResources().getString(beepStringId);
                list.add(str);
            }
            return list;
        }


    }
```

I tried it with the `Switch` statement with `position` but that only set the `ImageView` to the `RowItem` that is on the position thats written in the `case` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a `switch-case` statement based on the text of the `TextView` like below

```
switch(tv.getText().toString()){

                case "Title1" : image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_title1);
                    break;

                case "Title2" : image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_title2);
                    break;

                default:
                    //Default image here, if no case found
                break;
}
```

Note: above answer requires JRE 1.7 compliance

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this.

```
image.setImageResource(getImageId(this, "ic_" + tv.getText().toString().toLowerCase());
```

So basically you're getting the title from the text view manipulating it to be in the format you're storing your images and calling the below helper to get the correct image id.

```
public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution in this instance would be to add methods for getting and setting the individual fields for your `ListView` object. For example, since you have a `TextView` and an `ImageView` in your row item, let us assume that your row object looks something like the following:

```
public class ListObject
{

    public ListObject (String textView, String imageView)
    {
        super();
        this.textView                      = textView;
        this.imageView                     = imageView;
    }

    private String     textView;
    private String     imageView;

    public String getTextView ()
    {
        return textView;
    }

    public void setTextView (String pTextView)
    {
        this.textView = pTextView;
    }

    public String getImageView ()
    {
        return imageView;
    }

    public void setImageView (String pImageView)
    {
        this.imageView = pImageView;
    }
}
```

Once these are implemented, you can easily set your `ImageView` based on your `TextView` like so:

```
// As an example, let us use the first list item
ListObject listObject = (ListObject) parent.getItemAtPosition(0);

if (listObject.getTextView == "Title1")
{
    listObject.setImageView("NameOfResource");
}
// so on and so forth
```

Comment: Why implement a whole new object? All the data is in the adapter already.