# Android - how can you use a counter in the java file to locate a resource/image name?

Tags: android, android-drawable

Is there a way to use a counter in a java file to set a resource/drawable/image to a variable?

For instance:

Layout file

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageHolder"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
```

Java file

```
int index = 0;

ImageView imgHolder =(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgHolder);
Drawable  drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img<index>);
imgHolder.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

I'm sure this isn't possible like this, but I just wanted to give an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

I would just want to get around what I feel is inevitable, ie:

```
if(index == 1)
{
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img1);
    imgHolder.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
else if(index == 2)
{
    drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.img2);
    imgHolder.setImageDrawable(drawable);
}
else if(index == 3)
etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my answer here [How to add ImageView's that are depending on the text of the TextView in a ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28159521/3724365)

```
image.setImageResource(getImageId(this, "img" + index);
```

So basically you're getting the number from your counter and manipulating it to be in the format you're storing your images and calling the below helper to get the correct image id.

```
public static int getImageId(Context context, String imageName) {
    return context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + imageName, null, context.getPackageName());
}
```

Comment: Great, looks like it's working, but now I'm not sure how to check if the image file exists.  If it doesn't exist, I want to perform an action (or put up a default image).  But when I checked if the image == null, I got an error.

Comment: getImageId should return 0 if the resource doesn't exist

Comment: Alright I'll try that.  I've done all kinds of searching to check if image exists and I wasn't able to come to that conclusion.